# How to submit/distribute a build to App store connect from a different account with admin access

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a new build v3 -> v4 to app store connect using xcode(also tried Transporter same error.) but it gives provisioning profile error. Even though I have admin access but I cannot generate provisioning profile for it. Xcode cannot find it automatically as well.

I've tried removing account and log in again but still doesn't show the team for which the app belongs to.

When i goto app store connect in safari I can see the app in the team but when I open certificates and identifiers. I don't find neither the team nor the app.

If anyone has any idea please let me know as documentation says I should be able to create and upload build but I've been stuck for a week trying to figure out why I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to create/upload builds due to the fact that the Client's account is a Developer(Personal) Account and not Enterprise(Business) account, and Apple doesn't allow personal account apps to be uploaded from a different account even if you have admin access.